# Helper method to check if 3 numbers match some of the valid results

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this helper method to check if 3 numbers match some of the valid results (`XXX+bool`, `XXX`, `-XX`, `X-X`, `XX-`, `--X`).

```
const categoryNumber = (numbers, myBool, resultNumbers) => {
  const matches = numbers.map((val, index) => val === resultNumbers[index]);
  if (matches[0] && matches[1] && matches[2] && myBool) return 1;
  if (matches[0] && matches[1] && matches[2]) return 2;
  if (matches[0] && matches[1]) return 3;
  if (matches[1] && matches[2]) return 4;
  if (matches[0] && matches[2]) return 5;
  if (matches[2]) return 6;
  return 0;
};
```

Type vars?:

```
numbers:       numeric array size 3
myBool:        boolean
resultNumbers: numeric array size 3
```

Comment: @m_callens my fault, `matches` is inside method, corrected, thanks

Comment: have you considered using regex

Comment: @tolani how would you do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a look up table, as follows:

```
var obj = { 'XXX': 2, '-XX': 3, 'X-X': 4, 'XX-': 5, '--X': 6}
var match = ""+ matches[0] + matches[1] + matches[2];
```

and then

```
if(match === 'XXX' && myBool){ return 1; } else { return obj[match]; }
```

This assumes that each position in your matches will be either an X or a -.

Comment: To further improve this answer, you can remove the `else { ... }` and simply `return obj[match];`